# ¿Como sustituyo estos carácteres que salen al desencriptar?

Tags: php, php7

estoy utilizando un algoritmo de cifrado, para encriptar la información que envio entre páginas, el caso es que al querer recuperarlas obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así pero con muchos más campos, el caso es que aveces salen campos bien y otros mal.

Mi función para encriptar y desencriptar es la siguiente:

```
$clave_privada = 'fc9e77da1ea9d35cdbaf3a46c2fe2ab3';
function encriptar($message, $encryption_key)
{
  $key = hex2bin($encryption_key);
  $nonceSize = openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-ctr');
  $nonce = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($nonceSize);
  $ciphertext = openssl_encrypt(
    $message,
    'aes-256-ctr',
    $key,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
    $nonce
  );
  return base64_encode($nonce . $ciphertext);
}
function desencriptar($message, $encryption_key)
{
  $key = hex2bin($encryption_key);
  $message = base64_decode($message);
  $nonceSize = openssl_cipher_iv_length('aes-256-ctr');
  $nonce = mb_substr($message, 0, $nonceSize, '8bit');
  $ciphertext = mb_substr($message, $nonceSize, null, '8bit');
  $plaintext = openssl_decrypt(
    $ciphertext,
    'aes-256-ctr',
    $key,
    OPENSSL_RAW_DATA,
    $nonce
  );
  return $plaintext;
}
```

Para pasar la información entre páginas:

```
<a href ="?module=ficha-contrata&id_contrata=<?php echo encriptar($vd_array[$n]['id_contrata'],$clave_privada);?>&nif=<?php echo encriptar($vd_array[$n]['nif'],$clave_privada);?>&nombre=<?php echo encriptar($vd_array[$n]['nombre'],$clave_privada);?>&descripcion=<?php echo encriptar($vd_array[$n]['descripcion'],$clave_privada);?>&poblacion=<?php echo encriptar($vd_array[$n]['poblacion'],$clave_privada);?>&provincia=<?php echo encriptar($vd_array[$n]['provincia'],$clave_privada);?>&telefono=<?php echo encriptar($vd_array[$n]['telefono'],$clave_privada);?>&direccion=<?php echo encriptar($vd_array[$n]['direccion'],$clave_privada);?>&email=<?php echo encriptar($vd_array[$n]['email'],$clave_privada);?>&cp=<?php echo encriptar($vd_array[$n]['cp'],$clave_privada);?>"><i class="material-icons" title="Ver Ficha">&#xe851;</i></a>
```

Y un ejemplo de su recogida:

```
$id_contrata = desencriptar ($_GET['id_contrata'],$clave_privada);
```

No entiendo si es culpa de la recogida o es una falla en la función.
Si alguien puede tener idea de por que es, lo agradecería.

Comment: Considera configurar una codificación adecuada a nivel global en cada entorno: PHP, HTML y también archivos y/o base de datos en caso de estar trabajando con datos almacenados o fuentes de datos externas. No dices nada al respecto en tu pregunta y es un aspecto importante para encontrar una solución definitiva a problemas de este tipo.

Comment: Buenas, ante todo gracias por tu respuesta, creo que he formulado bien la pregunta, concretamente necesito transformar en utf8 lo que desencripte, a pesar de usar utf8_encode(), no obtengo resultado, la unica definición que tengo en el documento es en el header de html como utf8.

Comment: @StackGF para mi el problema se debe a que se esta cortando el valor de la variable. Intenta imprimirlos usando `urlencode`, por ejemplo, `<?php echo urlencode(encriptar($valor, $clave_privada)); ?>`. Avisame si funcionó y creo una respuesta.

Comment: @Marcos Muchas gracias :) messirve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema parece que se debe a que el valor de la variable `id_contrata` se esta cortando, y al decodificarlo se genera un resultado inválido.

Para evitar que esto suceda, es recomendable que al imprimir un valor como *"parámetro de consulta"* (`query param`) utilices [`urlencode`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.urlencode.php)

#### Ejemplo:

```php
<a href ="?id_contrata=<?php echo urlencode(encriptar($valor, $clave_privada));?>">
```